# How to integrate silverlight with XNA

Tags: facebook, silverlight, xna, windows-phone-8, xna-4.0

I have an existing XNA app for Windows phone 8. I have to integrate Silverlight for accessing Facebook from my game. So I would like to create a Silverlight app, and I just want to use Facebook login and return a token from facebook. Is there any other way in XNA, or I would like to get support for using Silverlight in an XNA app.

**Mine is a pure XNA app, does not have XAML Contents. I have created the app as pure XNA** , Even menus are controlled by XNA, so i would like to know how I can convert this to XAML (if it's needed for Silverlight) with minimal effort.

Please let me know if there is any other methods to have head to head gaming in XNA with Facebook friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the [Silverlight-XNA sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/silverlight_xna_game_components)? That's the closest you can get to what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi chad , thanks for the help, but i downloaded the sample but i dont seen any Silverlight-XNA sample , could u help to find that , i dont see any reference of silverlight in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SilverSprite](http://silversprite.codeplex.com/), which should be all you need.

Their website:

`Run XNA games without code changes in Silverlight. Since the game compiles into straight Silverlight code, it will run anywhere that Silverlight can. Now with support for Silverlight 5 Toolkit's SpriteBatch and other XNA compatibility.`

Comment: thanks, i wanted it to work on windows phone 8, as native . as when i integrate to silverlight